# Upgrading an DHCP Load Balance environment - in-place upgrading 2012R2 to 2022

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, upgrade

I've got an old DHCP environment, all on Win 2012 R2. 2 host doing Load Balance . We want to upgrade those to Win 2022.

That's something I've never done before (heck, I set this current one up like 10 years ago, I barely remember that LOL).

What would be the best way of going about this? The DHCP hosts shouldn't be too big a deal.

Anyone done this? Or have a link to a sequence I can look at?

Comment: upgrade path: 2012r2 > 2019 >2022 do a snapshot each time and your fine and remember to do a backup infront of the Action

Comment: Thanks man btw does supported dhcp server in place upgrade ?

Comment: any non Cert/AD-Services can be easy inplace upgraded. as reminder always do a full backup of the device and then if in case of a VM do additional a Snapshot.